# Constructing an F[x]-module from a vector space V.

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

I'm working through Dummit and Foote (module theory), and I'm having a tough time understanding the following:

for any two linear transformations $A,B$ from $V$ to $V$ and elements $\alpha,\beta\in F$, let $\alpha A+\beta B$ be defined by
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha A+\beta B)(v)=\alpha(A(v))+\beta(B(v))
\end{equation*}
where $F$ is a field and $V$ is a vector space over $F$.

Shouldn't this be
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha A+\beta B)(v)=\alpha A(v)+\beta B(v)
\end{equation*}

Is this a typo or do I have a misunderstanding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the two things you wrote are the same by most conventions!

Comment: Wow, my bad. I have been doing too much homological algebra (I want every set of parantheses to mean I have a function!) Thank you!

Comment: Well, in some sense, for vector spaces, scalars *are* functions. More precisely, an $F$-vector space is an abelian group $A$ paired with a ring homomorphism $F \to \operatorname{End}(A)$. In other words, a vector space structure on an abelian group gives us a way to interpret each scalar $\alpha \in F$ as an endomorphism of the abelian group (called "scalar multiplication by $\alpha$").